# How to get HWND in win32?

Tags: c++, winapi

Is there way to get the HWND handler of my window?
I'm using win32.

Comment: yea...  But my class needs it.  I know how to do it by keep passing it as variable but i want something like function to get it for me instead of passing it

Comment: HWND handler... do you mean the window procedure?

Comment: @Ramilol: "i want something like function to get it" - Yes, that function would be `CreateWindow()`. You have to keep the returned value somewhere so you can refer to your own window later.

Comment: The one i get from CreateWindow().

Comment: So pass it once to the class constructor then store it in your class?

Comment: I know that...  I was just curious if there is function that can get it for me..

Comment: @Ramilol: That question makes no sense. The HWND you get from `CreateWindow()` uniquely identifies your window. That's how you can refer to the window later. That's how the OS knows which window you're talking about when you want to manipulate it or inspect it.

Comment: what do you mean ? The WindowProcedure (which handles the messages send to your window)? If so you shouldn't use it directly. Use SendMessage and PostMessage instead. The only reason you need your WindowProcedure is for sub- and superclassing.

Comment: um... `CreateWindow()` returns the HWND. than, i store it somewhere, than pass it to my class. this is how i do it.  I'm just asking if win32 has function that passes HWND of my window, by not creating a window

Comment: @Ramilol: "I'm just asking if win32 has function that passes HWND of my window, by not creating a window" - Huh? Ask yourself: What is the HWND of a nonexisting window?

Comment: @Ramilol: One other way to retrieve a HWND is via your windows procedure. But it's not a function that you call - it's something the operating system calls to allow your application to perform whatever processing it needs.

Comment: @Ramilol:  I don't know why people are harshing you about this.  It's a perfectly valid question that is stated clearly enough, given that English is obviously not your primary language.  It's true that using GetActiveWindow() is probably not the best way to do this, but there *is a way to do what you're trying to do*.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could call GetActiveWindow to get the active control in your application, then repeatedly call GetParent on the returned handle until it returns NULL. The last valid handle you get should be the handle of your main window.

The easier way as someone else said is to store the returned value from CreateWindow somewhere.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question.  Keep in mind that there are lots of scenarios where this won't work the way you expect or the way you want.  It's best to not rely on GetActiveWindow if at all possible, unless what you *really* want is the active window.

Answer (score 7):

It's probably good to understand why there is no simple way. It all boils down to "*which* window?". You'll likely have multiple windows visible on your screen, right now. For instance, the taskbar at the bottom of your screen is a window. even your own app typically has more than one. For instance, the "File Save" dialog is a window. Even the simple `MessageBox` is a window.

So, how do you identify *which* window you're talking about? The common answer is that you identify them by their `HWND`. So, to get the position of the "File Save" dialog window, you ask for the position associated with that HWND. Obviously, you can get any property that way, *except* the `HWND` itself ! It makes sense to ask the X/Y position of `HWND(0x5e21)`, but it's stupid to ask which `HWND` belongs to `HWND(0x5e21)`.

Now, it may happen that you have another more-or-less unique property and you want to get the `HWND` from that. For instance, you may have an X/Y position. In that case, `WindowFromPoint(xy)` will return the `HWND` at that position.

But the most common case is that you need to react to a Windows message for your window. In that case, you get the `HWND` of your window as the first argument of your `WindowProc()`.

So, unless you tell us what unique information you do have, we can't tell you how to find the matching `HWND`.

Answer (score 6):

Didn't you create your window via `CreateWindow()` or `CreateWindowEx()`? The [CreateWindowEx() function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680.aspx) and the [CreateWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679.aspx) function both return the `HWND` of the newly created window.

Also, the operating system passes you the `HWND` of your window(s) [via your window procedure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633573.aspx). It's not a function that you call; it's a function that the operating system calls to let your application do any processing that's needed.